# How do I pass a multiline string from Python to C using ctypes?

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have the following simple C function:

```
void pyentry(const char *config)
{
    printf("%s\n",config);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

My ctypes definition is as follows:

```
libc = ct.CDLL("./amr.so")
entry = wrap_function(libc, 'pyentry', ct.POINTER(Checkpoint), [ct.c_wchar_p])
json = "this is a test"
start = entry(json)
```

Where `wrap_function` is simply a wrapper for more easily defining ctypes access to C functions:

```
def wrap_function(lib, funcname, restype, argtypes):
    func = lib.__getattr__(funcname)
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    return func
```

I have compiled as a shared library and I am trying to call it, but in C it is only printing the first character of the string I send in. I am assuming this is because I have the wrong argument tpyes in my ctypes definition, but I am not having any luck figuring out out the right one.

Can someone tell me why my C function is only seeing the first character in the passed string?

Comment: Hint: what's the difference between `char` and `wchar_t`?

Comment: I managed to get it working using `ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)` as the type. Thanks for the hint. I do not know why I didn't start with that.

Comment: `pyentry` is `void`, so `.restype` shoud be `None`.  `.argtypes` shoudl be `[ct.c_char_p]`.   `getattr(lib,funcname)` is more Pythonic.  `start = entry(json)` should just be `entry(json)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
entry = wrap_function(libc, 'pyentry', None, [ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)])
json = "this is a test".encode('utf-8')
```

`pyentry` takes `const char*` and returns `void`. So `argtypes` and `restype` could be `[ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)]` and `None`.

And `char*` points a sequence of bytes, not Python string. So `json` should be converted to bytes.